# "Change in meaning (or role, or use)" vs "Change of meaning (or role, or use)

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I'm slightly confused. I'm editing my notes from an introductory lecture to grammar and I found this:

> A change in the form of the word in order to express a change in the
>   use, meaning or role in the sentence.

What difference would it make to the meaning if I wrote "A change of the form of the word", if any? "Change of the meaning"? "Change of the role"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Change in" allows for the possibility that some hint of the original use or meaning survives, though altered.  "Change of" is what you would use if it had completely changed, such that the original use or meaning completely disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, you know that this is not a sentence, right? *Change of the form* or *change in the form* are both ok if you are talking about the action of transforming a word.

The second we would probably almost aleays write *change in* if it's something that occurs due to such a transformation.